# How to have multiple prices for 1 product (nopcommerce)

Tags: c#, e-commerce, nopcommerce

My clients needs to have a functionality where for one product he has price for dealers, wholesale price, and retail price. And then users with role guests could see only retail price. Users with role wholesalers could see only wholesale price and dealers could see only dealers price. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Maybe there is a specific solution out of the box in nopcommerce? I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use tier prices which can be applied per user role, without any customization. Make sure to add tier price record with quantity set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Store 3 prizes in the DB for each product and retrieve and use it based on the Role. And in Code you may use any 2-Key Collection to store it.

Syntax :

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> ;
```

or

```
IDictionary<Tuple<K1, K2>, V>
```

Comment: do you know in what place I can get this change in nopcommerce? I mean in code?